# Php foreach array (then split index)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have into $_POST array all the data i need.

If I `print_r` the array, I see something like this:

```
Array (
  [0_45_115] => 01
  [0_46_115] => 01
  [0_47_115] => 01
  [0_48_115] => 01
  [0_49_115] => 01
  [0_50_115] => 01
  [0_51_115] => 01
  [0_52_115] => 01
  [0_53_115] => 01
  [0_54_115] => 01
  [0_55_115] => 01
  [0_56_115] => 01
  [0_57_115] => 01
  [0_58_115] => 01
  [0_59_115] => 01
  [0_60_115] => 01
  [0_61_115] => 01
  [0_62_115] => 01
  [0_63_115] => 01
  [0_64_115] => 01
  [0_65_115] => 01
  [0_66_115] => 01
  [0_67_115] => 01
)
```

The index i post from the form (the `name attr`) doesn't have underscores.  For example:

```
<input type="text" name="0 45 115" value="" />
```

Let's forget this.

`0_45_115` which the index is will provide me all the neccessery data I want to update or insert a new row into my database.  The value will saw me the information I want.

The problem is that I don't know how to manage the array.  Maybe I must use `foreach` method, and the I will use `split` function to split the index of each row.  Then I will do all the other stuff for insertion/update my database.

I ask how can I use `foreach` to take the info (index-data) from `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are converted to underscores per PHP specifications. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) for more details.  Specifically, search for this string in the page: *Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores.*

I think the right approach would be

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $key);    //split your $key
    //then deal with corresponding $value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/array_keys) function.
It will return all the keys of the input array, than you can use the [split()](https://www.php.net/split) function to work on the keys and get the data you need.

For example:

```
$keys = array_keys($yourArray);
foreach($keys as $k) {
    $data = split("_", $k);
    print $data[0];
    print $data[1];
    print $data[2];

}
```

Comment: it seems that's what i am looking for..
Do you have any explanation of underscores mr gualano?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a little example of the split() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $yourArray as $k => $v ) { 

   $keys = explode( "_", $k) // for first iterate you will get array('0','45','115')

}
```

Comment: your solution is better..
I must learn object oriented php and PDO, but no free time unfortunatelly..:(
Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a loop, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
array_map(function ($str) {return explode('_', $str);}, 
          array_keys($_POST));
```

Result:

```
array (
  array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '45',
    2 => '115',
  ),
  array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '46',
    2 => '115',
  ),
  array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '47',
    2 => '115',
  ),
  ...
```

Since only PHP 5.3 and newer have anonymous functions at the language level, a loop is the better choice if you need to support earlier PHP versions. Otherwise, you have to use `create_function`, which is just ugly.